# Using google hack to find webshops

Tags: search

I do not know, what stackexchange page related to this question.

I want to write a study about different webshops. I'd like to visit them and in several countries.

So I'd like to group them by countries, types, etc...

For example: I need to search woocommerce webpages in US, Brazil, Russia, Germany, etc...

I've set the google search for language: english, region: us, and wrote this into the search bar for US: `site:.com inurl:wp-content`

My ISP in Netherlands, and for some reason I am getting sites from this country.

The other problem is the sites are not webshops. I've tried `intext: webshop`, but I've got results about hosting companies, or webshop solution companies. `intext: basket` not helps either.

I've also tried `inurl:woocommerce` but I've just got pages about the plugin, or ecommerce solutions, not real webshops.

Can somebody help me, how to improve my search to get real webshops?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few reasons why you might not get your desired results:

`wp-content` is folder related to Wordpress and contains all user-uploaded content, such as images and videos. Wordpress is not Woocommerce.

`site:.com`. A `.com` domain doesn't necessarily define the country of the webshop. It is also often used as a redirect link.

`intext: basket`. Basket is also and item. You are asking search engine to search for that item. Also consider that websites in other countries might use translations of this url slug.

My personal advice:
You could also reconsider if you should change your research approach. Maybe narrow it down to something more specific, or niche. Maybe do a qualitative research with less data, especially if you want to visit some of these places.

Good luck.